# Why is the sample size of stochastic gradient descent a power of 2?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, stochastic-gradient-descent

I watched the video lecture of cs224: [Stanford CS224N: NLP with Deep Learning | Winter 2019 | Lecture 2 – Word Vectors and Word Senses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEMJRjEdNzM&list=PLoROMvodv4rOhcuXMZkNm7j3fVwBBY42z&index=2).

They take the sample size of the window to be $2^5 = 32$ or $2^6 = 64$. Why is the sample size of stochastic gradient descent a power of 2? Why not we can take 42 or 53 as the sample window size?

Btw, how do I identify the best minimum window sample size?

Comment: I'm not sure of a specific reason, but it could just be that using powers of 2 is computationally and memory efficient, as information in a computer is stored as binary, so in powers of 2. If you use a number such as 53, there's a bunch of under-utilised bytes. It's generally good practice to stick to powers of 2 for most computational things if you have the choice.